# Performance Counters for all processes with same name?

Tags: c#, memory-management, cpu, process, performancecounter

I am currently running nginx on my windows system and am making a little control panel to show statistics of my web server.

I'm trying to get the performance counters for the CPU Usage and Memory Usage for the process but nginx shows as more than one process, it can vary from 2 - 5 depending on the setting in the configuration file. My setting shows two processes, so nginx.exe and nginx.exe

I know what performance counters to use, `% Processor Time` and `Working Set - Private` but how would I be able to get the individual values of both processes so i can add them together for a final value?

I tried using the code found at [Waffles question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703166/how-can-i-use-performance-counters-in-c-to-monitor-4-processes-with-the-same-nam) but it only could output the values for the first process out of the two.

Thanks.

EDIT - Working Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
                    {
                        //i = i + 1;
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            toPopulate = new PerformanceCounter
                                ("Process", "Working Set - Private",
                                 toImport[i].ProcessName,
                                 true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            toPopulate = new PerformanceCounter
                                ("Process", "Working Set - Private",
                                 toImport[i].ProcessName + "#" + i,
                                 true);
                        }

                        totalNginRam += toPopulate.NextValue();

                        instances[i] = toPopulate;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the accepted answer to that question. Try running `perfmon`. Processes that have the same names will be identified as something like this `process#1`, `process#2`, etc. In your case it could be `nginx#1`, `nginx#2`, etc.

Edit:

You need to pass the instance name to either the appropriate [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/356cx381.aspx) or the `InstanceName` property. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.instancename.aspx), it looks like the proper format is to use underscore. So, `process_1`, `process_2`.

Comment: If it were nginx#2 how would I be able to choose that as the identifier?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try it out once I'm working on the application.

Comment: Yep changing the instance name worked, I've updated my question with the updated working code for anyone that wants to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

When using Azure Log Analytics, you can specify a path such as

```
Process(nginx*)\% Processor Time
```

This seems to be collecting data from all processes that match the wildcard pattern at any time. I can confirm that it picks up data from new processes (started after changing the settings) and it does not pick up data from "dead" processes. However, the `InstanceName` (such as `nginx#3`) may be reused, making it hard to tell when a process was "replaced" by a new one.

I have not been able to do this in Performance Monitor. The closest thing is to type "nginx*" in the search box of the "Add Counters" dialog, then select `<All searched instances>`. This will create one counter per process, and counters will not be dynamically added or removed as processes are started or stopped.

Perhaps it can be done with data collector sets created via PowerShell. However, even if you are able to set a path with a wildcard in the instance part, it is not guaranteed that it will behave as you expect (i.e., automatically collect data from all processes that are running at any time).